# Component.find returns elements not on page

Tags: aura-attribute, aura-iteration

I have an array of sections, which are objects that each contain an array of fields. If I reset this array and then look for the fields using component.find(), it returns many more fields than display on the page.

Here is the simplest example I could use to recreate it:

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >
    <aura:attribute name="sections" type="List"/>
    
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.sections}" var="section" indexVar="sectionNum">
        <aura:iteration items="{!section.fields}" var="f" indexVar="fieldNum"> 
            <lightning:textarea aura:id="input" name="{!'test:'+sectionNum+':'+fieldNum}" value="{!f.value}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </aura:iteration>
    
    <lightning:button label="Refresh Array" onclick="{!c.refreshArray}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    refreshArray : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.sections', [
            {fields:
             [ {value: 'test 1'}, {value: 'test 2'}]
            }
        ]);
        var inputs = component.find('input'); 
        console.log("component.find('input').length: "+inputs.length);  
    }
})
```

This correctly displays 2 fields no matter how many times the button is clicked. However, inputs.length is 6 after the first button click on all subsequent clicks:

Console after 4 clicks:

```
component.find('input').length: 2
component.find('input').length: 6
component.find('input').length: 6
component.find('input').length: 6
```

Note that in reality I am getting data from the server so updating the existing array rather than resetting does not seem efficient. There are workarounds, but I'd like to understand why this is happening. Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because rendering is an asynchronous process. This feature allows you to set an attribute multiple times, and set many different attributes, without multiple reflows. This is a performance enhancement in Aura, LWC, and many other frameworks.

You can get the correct results by waiting for a rendering cycle:

```
({
    refreshArray : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.sections', [
            {fields:
             [ {value: 'test 1'}, {value: 'test 2'}]
            }
        ]);
        setTimeout($A.getCallback(() => {
          var inputs = component.find('input'); 
          console.log("component.find('input').length: "+inputs.length);  
        });
    }
})
```

The setTimeout method, without a second parameter, will wait until the next available time when the browser isn't doing anything, which will be after the next render cycle completes.